# Remove trendline from ANCOVA plot in ggplot

Tags: r

I am doing a one-way ANCOVA analysis on root colonisation data using the following example https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/ancova-in-r/. I am trying to remove the trendline from the resulting plot as my treatments are separate groups so I don't think it is necessary. I have tried using each of the following but I can't get any to work with this code. Is there another way I can go about this? Thanks!

```
+geom_line(linetype = “blank”)
color = "white"
plot_type = c("p")
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(broom)
library(emmeans)

data("anxiety", package = "datarium")

anxiety <- anxiety %>%
  select(id, group, t1, t3) %>%
  rename(pretest = t1, posttest = t3)
anxiety[14, "posttest"] <- 19

anxiety %>% anova_test(posttest ~ group*pretest)
res.aov <- anxiety %>% anova_test(posttest ~ pretest + group)
pwc <- anxiety %>% 
  emmeans_test(
    posttest ~ group, covariate = pretest,
    p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"
    )
pwc
get_emmeans(pwc)
pwc <- pwc %>% add_xy_position(x = "group", fun = "mean_se")

ggline(get_emmeans(pwc), x = "group", y = "emmean") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0.2) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc, hide.ns = TRUE, tip.length = FALSE) +
  labs(
    subtitle = get_test_label(res.aov, detailed = TRUE),
    caption = get_pwc_label(pwc)
  )
```

[ggline plot showing ANCOVA results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKhTG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way you could cheat this is by making it a boxplot instead and using the error bar as the IQR that surrounds the median. The problem is that your option uses ggline, which usually has to map a line to each group, and this way isn't as pretty, but it still achieves the purpose you are looking for:

```
ggboxplot(get_emmeans(pwc), x = "group", y = "emmean") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high),
                width = 0.2) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc, hide.ns = TRUE, tip.length = FALSE) +
  labs(
    subtitle = get_test_label(res.aov, detailed = TRUE),
    caption = get_pwc_label(pwc)
  )
```

Which makes this:

[image]

Or you can do something similar to what you did without a line by making it a scatter instead. The plot will just dot the median:

```
ggscatter(get_emmeans(pwc), x = "group", y = "emmean") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high),
                width = 0.2) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc, hide.ns = TRUE, tip.length = FALSE) +
  labs(
    subtitle = get_test_label(res.aov, detailed = TRUE),
    caption = get_pwc_label(pwc)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: No prob! Was actually surprised I had an answer haha